# McLaurin series for cosine

Tags: python

I want to make a cosine function that relies on the McLaurin expansion on cosine.. but it doesn't work: it should return me '-1.0..something' but it returns me another value, please can you guys help me??

code:

```
import math
def _cos(n:float,prec:int):
    a = []
    k = 0.0
    for x in range(prec):
        a.append(
          ((-1)**k)*((n**(2*k+1))/(2*k+1))
        )
        k+=1
    z = 0
    for x in a:
        z+=x
    return z
pi = math.pi
print(_cos(pi,200))
print(math.cos(pi))
```

Comment: 'it doesn't work' isn't very helpful. What doesn't work?

Comment: it should return me cos(pi) that is equal to -1.0 but returns me 628.3185307180015

Comment: You increment k outside of the for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. your formula of mac laurin is false: see [maclaurin cosinus](https://blogs.ubc.ca/infiniteseriesmodule/units/unit-3-power-series/taylor-series/the-maclaurin-expansion-of-cosx/)
2. in your loop, you do a mixture with the pow (x is the pow not k)

your correct code will be:

```
def _cos(n:float,prec:int):
    a = []
    for x in range(prec):
        a.append(
          ((-1)**x)*((n**(2*x))/factorial(2*x))
        )

    z = 0
    for x in a:
        z+=x
    return z
pi = 3.14159265359
print(_cos(pi,200))
print(math.cos(pi))
```

but if you do that with a precision of 200, you will be an overflow
try with 10 is already best.

i suggest you to use the precicion not from a number of iteration but from the difference between old value and new value like this :

```
def _cos(n:float,prec:float):
    k = 0
    cosine_x = 0.0
    while True:
        old = cosine_x + (pow(-1, k) * pow(n, 2 * k) / factorial(2 * k))
        #print(old)
        if 0 < abs(old - cosine_x) < prec:
            return old
        cosine_x = old
        k += 1

pi = 3.14159265359
print(_cos(pi,0.000000000000001))
print(cos(pi))
```

Answer (score 2):

As I can see you don't have the good formula.

```
((-1)**k)*((n**(2*k+1))/(2*k+1))
```

it's n**(2*n)

then you need to divide it by the factorial of 2n

4! = 4 * 3 * 2 * 1

2n! = 2n * 2n-1 * 2n-2 * 2n-3 ...

Answer (score 1):

You were not updating `k`, as you used `x` for the range and you were missing the `factorial` function in the division. Try with precison as 20, but 200 is too high.
Try the following code:

```
import math

def _cos(n:float,prec:int):
    a = []
    k = 0
    for k in range(prec):
        a.append(
          ((-1)**k) * ((n**(2*k))) /
          math.factorial(2*k)
          )
    z = 0
    for x in a:
        z += x
    return z
```